# Image keeps on repeating although it is already randomized

Tags: java

I'm developing a simple game where all the images are randomized. I've noticed that some of the image are repeated although I have put the random code. I'm still new to Java. I hope that someone can help me solve my problem. Below is my coding.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Task1 extends JFrame implements KeyListener,ActionListener {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("FYP");
    JTextField textField = new JTextField();
    JButton btnNext = new JButton("NEXT"); 

    int sum=0;
    int Error=0;int total_test = 0;
    static String inputID;
    static int index;
    String[] imgFileHP = {"1.jpg","3.jpg","4.jpg","7.jpg","9.jpg","10.jpg","12.jpg","16.jpg","17.jpg","18.jpg"};
    String[] imgNo = {"5","4","6","3","5","3","4","4","6","6"};
    int randomNo;
    Random rand = new Random();

public Task1(String inputID)
{
    frame.setSize(2200,2500);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);  
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));       

    Task(inputID);
}

public void Task(String inputID)
{
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JLabel labelUsername = new JLabel("");

    frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(imgFileHP));
    Set<Integer> uniqueList = new HashSet<Integer>();//This would create list with the number 0 to 9
    for(int count=0;count<imgFileHP.length;count++){
        uniqueList.add(count);
        labelUsername.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/image/" + imgFileHP[count])));
        if(!uniqueList.isEmpty()){
            index =  (int) (Math.random() * (upper - lower)) + lower;

            if(uniqueList.contains(index)){

               uniqueList.remove(index);//particular number is delete from the list so that duplicate images doesnt show up
               System.out.println(imgFileHP[r]);//This printf statement is just for your reference
            }   
        }


    }
    textField.setText("");
    textField.setColumns(10);
    textField.addKeyListener(this);     

    btnNext.addActionListener(this);

    panel.add(labelUsername);
    panel.add(textField);
    panel.add(btnNext);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
{

    if(!textField.getText().equals("")){
        total_test += 1;
        if(isNumeric(textField.getText())){
            //********************Correct Integer**********************
            if(Integer.valueOf(imgNo[randomNo])==Integer.valueOf(textField.getText())){
                //********************Correct Answer**********************
                System.out.println("Correct");
                sum+=1;
            }else{
                //********************Incorrect Answer**********************
                System.out.println("Incorrect");
                Error+=1;
            }
            refreshFrame();
        }else{
            //********************Incorrect Integer/Alphabet**********************
            System.out.println("Invalid");
            Error+=1;
            refreshFrame();
        }
    }else{
        System.out.println("Null Input");
    }
    //System.out.println(Integer.valueOf(imgNo[randomNo]));
}
public void refreshFrame(){
    if(total_test>=10){
        // add result page to see how many score
        //Task2(sum, Error);
        System.out.println("Correct: "+sum+" Incorrect: "+Error);
        frame.dispose();
    }else{
        btnNext.removeActionListener(this);
        frame.getContentPane().removeAll();
        getContentPane().removeAll();
        Task(inputID);
    }

}

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Task1 a = new Task1(inputID);
    }
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public static boolean isNumeric(String str)  
    {  
      try  
      {  
          Integer.valueOf(str);  
      }  
      catch(NumberFormatException nfe)  
      {  
        return false;  
      }  
      return true;  
    }

}
```

EDIT part (But some of the image is still repeating.)

```
Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(imgFileHP));
    Set<Integer> uniqueList = new HashSet<Integer>();//This would create   list with the number 0 to 9
    for(int count=0;count<imgFileHP.length;count++){
        uniqueList.add(count);
    }

        if(!uniqueList.isEmpty()){
            index =  (int) (Math.random() * (upper - lower)) + lower;
            randomNo = index;
            if(uniqueList.contains(index)){
               labelUsername.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/image/" + imgFileHP[index]))); 
               uniqueList.remove(index);//particular number is delete from the list so that duplicate images doesnt show up
               System.out.println(imgFileHP[r]);//This printf statement is just for your reference
            }   
        }
```

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "some of the images are repeated"? You're picking a random number every time - so yes, you can get an image more than once, just like if you roll a regular die several times you'd expect to see the same numbers more than once. If you want to show each image exactly once, perhaps you should basically shuffle them and then go through the shuffled collection instead of picking a new random number each time?

Comment: Would u mind show me how to do it? I've read about shuffle but I just can't apply it to my coding.

Comment: Well that's a pretty broad description of the problem. I'd use a list rather than an array, and use `Collections.shuffle`. Note that instead of having two arrays, I'd have a *single* list, where each element in the list contained both the correct answer and the filename for the image...

Comment: If you’re otherwise fine with an array you may do `Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(myArrayOfBothImageAndNumber))`.

Comment: In your actionPerformed method, you should change Integer.valueOf to `Integer.parseInt`.  Comparing two int values with `==` is fine, but comparing two Integer objects with `==` is not.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how Random works. Even though you have mentioned `rand.nextInt(10);`but everytime it gets called, there is not pre-defined rule in java that it has to generate unique numbers and not the duplicate the previously generated ones.

For Example:
when you call - 
int index = rand.nextInt(10); // Index could be 2
index = rand.nextInt(10);  // Now again the value could be 2 as well

So what you need to do is you have to add an extra piece of code to check the uniqueness every time random is called.

Since you want to generate numbers between 0 to 10. Try the following code, it might help you understand.

```
String[] imgFileHP = {"1.jpg","3.jpg","4.jpg","7.jpg","9.jpg","10.jpg","12.jpg","16.jpg","17.jpg","18.jpg"};
        int upper = imgFileHP.length;
        int lower = 0;
        int r=0;
        int index=0;

        Set<Integer> uniqueList = new HashSet<Integer>();//This would create list with the number 0 to 9
        for(int count=0;count<imgFileHP.length;count++){
            uniqueList.add(count);
        }



        if(!uniqueList.isEmpty()){
            index =  (int) (Math.random() * (upper - lower)) + lower;

            if(uniqueList.contains(index)){

                uniqueList.remove(index);//particular number is delete from the list so that duplicate images doesnt show up
                System.out.println(imgFileHP[r]);//This printf statement is just for your reference
            }   
        }
```

Another easier method is to use Collections.Shuffle as shown below:

```
Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(imgFileHP));
```

Example of Collection.shuffle().

Lets say you have an array `String[] arr = {"abc","def","xyz","bla"}`

when you do `Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(arr));`

then print array from index 0 to 3. Array might be shuffled something like this: `{"def","bla","abc","xyz"}`

**EDIT 2:**Solution based on your edit in main code:

```
  for(int count=0;count<imgFileHP.length;count++){//first add the counters into List 
            uniqueList.add(count);
        }


        if(!uniqueList.isEmpty()){
            index =  (int) (Math.random() * (upper - lower)) + lower;

            if(uniqueList.contains(index)){
               labelUsername.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/image/" + imgFileHP[index])));
               uniqueList.remove(index);//particular number is delete from the list so that duplicate images doesnt show up
               System.out.println(imgFileHP[r]);//This printf statement is just for your reference
            }   
        }
```

Comment: I have added Collections,shuffle(Arrays.asList(imgFileHP) but my image won't come out.

Comment: Here is the code that I put:          Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(imgFileHP));
labelUsername.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/image/" + imgFileHP)));

Comment: @MagC should it be imgFileHP[index]? that is here
`labelUsername.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/image/" + imgFileHP[count])));`
Here count will range from 1 to 10 or 0 to 9. Collections have already shuffled the array but you need to point to an index right?

Comment: I've tried the code you gave me but some of the image is still repeating.

Comment: 'Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(imgFileHP));
  Set<Integer> uniqueList = new HashSet<Integer>();//This would create list with the number 0 to 9
        for(int count=0;count<10;count++){
            uniqueList.add(count);
            labelUsername.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/image/" + imgFileHP[count])));
        }'  Did I do something wrong here?

Comment: Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(imgFileHP));
  Set<Integer> uniqueList = new HashSet<Integer>();//This would create list with the number 0 to 9
        for(int count=0;count<10;count++){
            uniqueList.add(count);
            labelUsername.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/image/" + imgFileHP[count])));
        }

Comment: do like this copy paste the entire code in the main question, posting as edit.. so that i can have a clear picture of what you are doing.. here code looks clumsy

Comment: ok do like this... after `labelUsername.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/image/" + imgFileHP[count])));` add this line :
               `uniqueList.remove(index);//particular number is delete from the list so that duplicate images doesnt show up`

Comment: I've edited the code in the main question but some of the image is still repeating

Comment: I  have pasted the solution in my reply as edit 2, check and let me know how it goes. you shouldn't run image displaying inside the same for loop as adding the counter. You are using count as your index in setIcon: `imgFileHP[count]` which should be changed to `imgFileHP[index]`

Comment: I've show the edit version in the main question but it still have the same problem. Why??

Comment: did you even check my edit 2 solution above? dont look at comments.. look at my reply...

Comment: You mention collections.shuffle is another method. Can you show me how to code using collections.shuffle?Where do I need to put the code?

Comment: We can do in Shuffle but we would be double shuffling is it ok? Once with HashSet and once with Collections.Shuffle().. is that what you want..